# "Total Discrepancies" in "Data Quality Rule" is counted twice for many fields, shwoing additional "no_data" entries

Tags: redcap

Using the *Data Quality Rules* in REDCap, I noticed that many fields are counted twice for each participant in the *Total Discrepancy* column. It counts the field value I am interested in, but also counts and shows a [no_data] entry.

A simple *Data Quality Rule* in REDCap such as

```
[linux_user] = 1
```

should calculate a '1' for the *Total Discrepancies* if the participant indicated that he or she is a Linux user.

However, when I try to calculate this with the *Data Quality Rule* tool, it will calculate 2(!) *Total Discrepancies* for one participant as follows:

```
Discrepant fields with their values:
*"Linux user?"*
linux_user: [no data]

*"Linux user?"*
linux_user: 1
```

I am not sure, if the instrument was saved once without entering a value and this is the reason that it is counted twice. The history for the field does not give any information on this. I asked a number of experienced REDCap users who also could not give any useful feedback. The REDCap documentation under "Help & FAQ" and online searches did not help to understand and resolve the problem.